# Generator function not working in PHP and results in an infinite loop

Tags: php, generator, infinite-loop

I have copied the code of the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#example-295

```
function gen_one_to_three() {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        // Note that $i is preserved between yields.
        yield $i;
    }
}

$generator = gen_one_to_three();
foreach ($generator as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
}
```

But when I run this code in the browser it results in an infinite loop:

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   1 ... Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 448 bytes)

Before *xdebug* informs me that the memory for the script has been exhausted.

I have PHP 5.6.2 installed on MAMP, why do I experience this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error! Did you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted Apache, same really really strange error...

Comment: Make sure you show us here your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: The code I have posted is the real and full code of the script, took it from the example on the manual.

Comment: And you have nothing else in your script/file ?

Comment: Yes, nothing else, I would have posted it...

Comment: @Rizier123 Check my answer, I have found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue, for all of those who like me are using the PHP AOP extension https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP:

Generators won't work, I have opened an issue on GitHub https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP/issues/93

In my `php.ini` I have changed this:

```
extension=aop.so
```

To this:

```
;extension=aop.so
```

Restarted Apache and now everything works perfectly as the manual says. So I guess there's a bug with the extension.